# How to create a distribution on CloudFront using Paws

Tags: amazon-web-services, perl, amazon-cloudfront

My goal is to create a basic CloudFront distribution using the [Paws sdk](https://metacpan.org/pod/Paws), and as of yet I have been unable to get past an error 400 with the following configuration:

```
use Paws;
use Data::Printer;

my $cloudfront = Paws->service('CloudFront');

my $CreateDistributionResult = $cloudfront->CreateDistribution(
DistributionConfig => {
  CallerReference      => "1578211502",
  Origins => {
    Quantity => 1,
    Items => [{
      DomainName => "foo.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com",
      Id => 'S3-Website-foo.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com'}]
  },
  DefaultCacheBehavior => {
    ForwardedValues => {
      Cookies => {Forward => 'none'},
      QueryString => 0
    },
    TargetOriginId => 'S3-Website-foo.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com',
    TrustedSigners => {
      Enabled  => 0,
      Quantity => 0
    },
    ViewerProtocolPolicy => 'redirect-to-https',
    MinTTL => 0
  },
  Comment              => "",
  Enabled => 1
  });

p $CreateDistributionResult;
```

The above is the complete set of only the required fields as defined in the api documentation [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/Paws::CloudFront::DistributionConfig) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-overview-required-fields.html). However, when I run the above it crashes with the following:

```
[foo@bar~]# perl aws.pl
Paws::CloudFront is not stable / supported / entirely developed at /root/perl5/lib/perl5/Paws/CloudFront.pm line 2.
Bad Request

Trace begun at /root/perl5/lib/perl5/Paws/Net/RestXMLResponse.pm line 24
Paws::Net::RestXMLResponse::process('Paws::Net::RestXMLResponse=HASH(0x2f275b8)', 'Paws::CloudFront::CreateDistribution=HASH(0x2fbe6e0)', 'Paws::Net::APIResponse=HASH(0x30c0ec0)') called at /root/perl5/lib/perl5/Paws/Net/Caller.pm line 46
Paws::Net::Caller::caller_to_response('Paws::Net::Caller=HASH(0x16d7bb8)', 'Paws::CloudFront=HASH(0x2a615f8)', 'Paws::CloudFront::CreateDistribution=HASH(0x2fbe6e0)', 'Paws::Net::APIResponse=HASH(0x30c0ec0)') called at /root/perl5/lib/perl5/Paws/Net/RetryCallerRole.pm line 19
Paws::Net::RetryCallerRole::do_call('Paws::Net::Caller=HASH(0x16d7bb8)', 'Paws::CloudFront=HASH(0x2a615f8)', 'Paws::CloudFront::CreateDistribution=HASH(0x2fbe6e0)') called at /root/perl5/lib/perl5/Paws/CloudFront.pm line 49
Paws::CloudFront::CreateDistribution('Paws::CloudFront=HASH(0x2a615f8)', 'DistributionConfig', 'HASH(0x2f9c500)') called at aws.pl line 6
```

What is a correct minimal call that would work here?

Comment: You might also try to ask at the [GitHub issues](https://github.com/pplu/aws-sdk-perl/issues)

Answer (score 1):

you don't have anything in the comment argument. Please try passing value there. 
AWS is a bit stingy with these kinds of things. Also please let me know if that fixes the issue or not.

Comment: No luck! I get the same error [with the comment in](https://pastebin.com/Sf1EeDvX) as well

Comment: Please have a look at this example which should help you https://github.com/pplu/aws-sdk-perl/blob/master/examples/cfn.pl

Comment: After opening an issue it looks like this part of the library is broken/not working: https://github.com/pplu/aws-sdk-perl/issues/367 - I'll update this question when there's a working version somewhere.